# Issue with DIV not showing in correct location - SOLVED

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am working on a project with other team members for school, and this file is one of the members contribution. It's his bio page with a recipe below it. Whatever I do, the div shows below the footer. I have a feeling it's conflicting in someway with the article, but I'm not entirely sure. I just know its showing below the footer even though in the code it's above it. Even the If you need to reach me, email me at wpope@troy.edu or message me on Canvas. appears above the div. The issue in question is near the bottom of the code in the recipe section, but I included the full file just in case. Can anyone help? Please excuse any beginner errors within the code, we are still learning. Maybe something to do with his stylesheet?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Group Project - William J. Pope</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

  ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.article {
    float: center;
    }

    .navigation {
    float: left;
    }

    .gpratt {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    }

    h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #8b0000;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Style the header */
header {
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}


nav {
  float: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

article {
  float: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


section:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


footer {
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/GroupProject/troy3.jpg" width="100%">
</header>

<section>
  <nav>
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="gpratt.html">Geoff Pratt</a>
  <a href="acruz.html">Alex Cruz</a>
  <a href="llee.html">Letabian Lee</a>
  <a href="wpope.html">William Pope</a>
  <a href="aalharbi.html">Abdulmohsen Alharbi</a>
</div>
  </nav>

  <article>
  <table style="float: left;">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <div class="article">
  <div class="navigation" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="gpratt.html">Geoff Pratt</a></li>
      <li><a href="acruz.html">Alex Cruz</a></li>
      <li><a href="llee.html">Letabian Lee</a></li>
      <li><a href="wpope.html">William Pope</a></li>
      <li><a href="aalharbi.html">Abdulmohsen Alharbi</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <table align="center" width="900px">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <div class="wpope">
  <h1>William Jerrod Pope</h1><br>
  <img src="http://prism.troy.edu/wpope/Group_Project/Photo_Jerrod.jpg" alt="Jerrod Pope" height = "250" border="1" align="right">
    My name is William Jerrod Pope but all my friends call me Jerrod. I'm a senior computer science student at Troy University and intend to graduate this coming May.
    I was born and raised in a small town called Jack, AL. I always had dreams of going far and seeing more of the world. I spent five months with the opportunity to study
    computer science hands on at Halmstad University in Halmstad, Sweden. Currently I'm back at Troy finishing my degree and getting ready for a move to France.<br><br> My hobbies
    include philosophy, cooking, and reading. I love the philosophy of Camus, Sartre, Foucoult, Hegel, and Kierkegaard. Food and Cuisine are probably what bring me the most joy in life. 
    The nuanced approach to what is both art and science has cemented it as my favorite part of life. Feel free to message me about philosophy and check out some of the simple recipes below.

        <!--
        RECIPE SECTION
    -->


<div class="closed" id="container">
  <header id="toggle">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="title">Huevos y Chorizo</div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">
  </header>
  <article>
    <ul class="ingredients">
      <li> 
        <div class="amount">2 - 3</div>
        <div class="ingredient">Eggs</div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="amount">2 oz</div>
        <div class="ingredient">Mexican Chorizo</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="amount">2 - 4</div>
        <div class="ingredient">Corn Tortillas</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="preperation"> 
      <div>Cook chorizo in medium pan until fat has rendered and the meat has browned, 5 minutes. </div>
      <div>Add eggs and scramble until set, about 3-5 mins. </div>
      <div>Place eggs in corn tortilla and garnish with your choice of salsa, cheese, crema, cilantro, etc.</div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>





<script>
        function byID(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

byID("toggle").onclick = function() {
  if (byID("container").classList.contains("closed")) {
    byID("container").classList.remove("closed");
  } else {
    byID("container").classList.add("closed");
  }
}
    </script>



    <br><br>If you need to reach me, email me at wpope@troy.edu or message me on Canvas.
</div>
 </td>
  </tr>
  </table>


  </article>
</section>

<footer>
  <p></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  position: absolute;
  top: 115%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#container.closed header { cursor: pointer; }
header { cursor: pointer; }

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  background: center / cover;
  background-image: url(http://prism.troy.edu/wpope/group_project/food.jpg);
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#container.closed .title {
  padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: -87px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.title:before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

#container.closed .title:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

article {
  padding: 25px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 400px;
} 

#container.closed article {
  max-height: 0px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.ingredients {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.ingredients > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 4px 0px;
}

.ingredients > li > .amount {
  width: 80px;
  color: #1976D2;
}

.preperation > div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It's because your `#container` is absolutely positioned.

Comment: I removed it and made it static? What can I do to accomplish getting this div under the paragraph and when expanded, fit within the window above the footer?

Comment: Well you have a max-height of 400px on the article for some reason.  I would remove that.  And also I would remove the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` on the #container.

Comment: Hey @GeoffPratt will you be able to paste all of this code and get this working on [codepen](https://codepen.io)? It's really hard too debug this when we can't visually see the final product

Comment: At the bottom of what range do you want #container to be?

body? .article?

Comment: Everything was fixed from your solutions Steven. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

remove position: absolute; and transform: translate(-50%, -50%); from #container

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 115%;
  left: 50%;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
```

you might want to remove the max-height: 400px; from the article too.

```
article {
    padding: 25px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* max-height: 400px; */
}
```